# Panda Group by time and count value of column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let say I have an array with event and log time, like this:

```
Time             Event
01/01/2019 8h00  X
01/01/2019 8h10  Y
01/01/2019 9h10  X
02/01/2019 7h10  Z
02/01/2019 8h10  Y
02/01/2019 9h10  Y
...
```

I want to have an output like this:

```
01/01/2019 [(X,2), (Y,1)]
02/01/2019 [(Y, 2), (Z,1)]
...
```

For now I only succeed to group by time and count all event or list all unique events

```
data = pd.read_csv('my.csv')    
s1 = data['Time'].groupby(data['Time'].dt.floor('d')).size()    
s2 = data.groupby(data['Time'].dt.floor('d')['Event'].unique().reset_index()
```

s1 output:

```
01/01/2019 3
02/01/2019 3
```

s2 output:

```
01/01/2019 [X, Y]
02/01/2019 [Y, Z]
```

How can I achieve to group by time and count the number of each events ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = (data.groupby(data['Time'].dt.floor('d'))['Event']
          .apply(lambda x: list(x.value_counts().items()))
          .reset_index())
print (df)
        Time             Event
0 2019-01-01  [(X, 2), (Y, 1)]
1 2019-02-01  [(Y, 2), (Z, 1)]
```

Comment: nice, can you tell me why `df['Time'].dt.floor('d')`  and why not `df['Time'].dt.date` under groupby, is there any major difference?

Comment: @anky_91 - yes, `df['date'].dt.date` return python objects `dates` and `df['Time'].dt.floor('d')` return datetimes with no times. Obviously in pandas is better working with datetimes like python objects.